# Swift: Getting a Label in TableView Prototype Cell to display multiple lines (word wrap)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, uistoryboard

I'm trying to setup a tableview which each cell will have an Image on the left, a Label which overlays the image, and finally a label to the right of the image with long text in which I would like for it wrap to the next line if needed.  My tableview row height is set at 65.

I have set the number of lines to 0 and set the line break to work wrap.

[image: Storyboard settings]

I even tried setting parameter programmatically in my CustomTableViewCell class:

```
    self.materialLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    self.materialLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.materialLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

I've tried many combinations of setting constraints on my label, but it either doesn't work or affects all objects in the cell with the image and image label out of sync.  The alignment constraints are not available to set.

Working with Xcode 6.3.2, Swift 1.2, and iOS 8

Thanks in Advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my label width was too wide.  I had to anchor my imageview and the imagelabel and set the width and height before setting the constraints on my label.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic cell height ( or self sizing cell).

Basically, you create `top`, `leading`, `bottom`, `trailing` label's constraints relative to cell's `contentView`.

and then set

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = someValue
```

---

http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually want a static cell height.  My table view row height is set 65.  I just need the labelview text to wrap.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to setup dynamic height for table cell.

If your not not using autolayout, you need to calculate table size programmatically and return using table view delegate method.

If your using autolayout, your life will be very easy. Add constraints to cell, I.e add border, width and height constraints to image. Add only 4 border constraints to image(don't add height constraint). This may not be the exact constraints, but this will give you a idea. Add following code in viewDidload

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = someValue
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I want the cell height to be static.  I just need the text to wrap.